# VSCode: How to add include path of project subDirectory?

Tags: c++, header, visual-studio-code

I just started using VSCode on linux Ubuntu environment and for past one day trying to include some header files from a sub-Directory (the project screen shot is shown below).

1. I have tired adding the header file path in include path but showing error.(Image below)
2. I also tired by provided complete path e.g. `/home/user/Work/Cpp_Test_Project/OpenFace/FaceAnalyser/include/` still it couldn't find the header file.
3. Also, If I try to include the header with local path e.g.

   `#include <OpenFace/LandmarkDetector/LandmarkCoreIncludes.h`

then all the internally linked header file doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The c_cpp_properties.json file is for configuring IntelliSense. The compiler you are using does not read from this file, so you will need to configure the include path for that separately. From what you have posted, it is unclear how you have set up your build.